# How to properly handle IOException for basicAck on RabbitMQ Channel when using Spring AMQP?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

When having declared a method like this using Spring AMQP:

```
@RabbitListener(..)    
public void myMethod(@Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long tag, ...)
```

and using manual acknowledge mode, how should one properly deal with the `IOException` that may be thrown when doing ACK:

```
try {
    channel.basicAck(tag, false);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // What to do here?
}
```

Should the exception be rethrown? Should the "basicAck" operation be retried? What's the proper way to handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is using retry mechanism & to come out if none of them succeeds.

However, based on my experience, if channel throws an exception, it more or less means the channel is useless & you might have to redo the whole thing again. I normally log the error along with the required details so that I can track which message processing failed so that I can verify the same later to see if its processed or I need to do anything about it.

Comment: When you say "redo the whole thing again", that's essentially what I want to do. But I'm concerned that since neither ACK nor NACK came through to RabbitMQ that the message is in "unack:ed" state and won't be reconsumed again by Spring until the application is restarted.

Comment: The exception is likely because the channel is closed for some reason; in which case the message will have gone back to ready automatically and will be redelivered. You could add a `try { close }...` to be sure, but that will likely fail too. Since your method may have already updated some other state, you will have to deal with a duplicate delivery.